# Force the return value of an interface property to be serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, interface

I have an interface with a property:

```
interface IFoo
{
  object Bar { get; }
}
```

Is there a way to instruct the implementing class, that the return value of `Bar` has to be a class that is serializable (marked with the SerializableAttribute)?

Comment: Seems with a little research that you are unable to put compile time constraints based upon an attribute. If your class implemented ISerializable, that would allow you to do what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since most attributes are evaluated at runtime (actually, it looks like the Serializable attribute is used at compile time, too, but I still don't think there's a way to constrain a type to it). Can you use the ISerializable interface, instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to force the return type of a property of an interface to be marked with `SerializableAttribute`.

You could consider using `ISerializable`, though it is not the same of course, and would force the type to implement the interface, rather than just be marked with the attribute.

```
interface IFoo
{
  ISerializable Bar { get; }
}
```